# Jquery: how to add css class to table cell by ordinal position

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a table with 7 columns and the last column has a button. One button will be there in the last column of all rows. Now I want when I click on any button in last column of any row then I need to add css class to 2nd, 3rd, 4th cell of that table row where button was clicked. How to achieve this by JQuery?

I could not come up with any code because I do not know how to access table cell by ordinal position of a row where button clicked occurred. Looking for idea to complete this.

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: here full sample html exist https://jsfiddle.net/qvy0y8sk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at following updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qvy0y8sk/7/

Here I have used `:nth-child` to locate the required cell:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit-user,.save-user").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").addClass("newClass");
    $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass("newClass");
    $(tr).find("td:nth-child(4)").addClass("newClass");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you bind on your buttons then in the handler you can find the parent row with

```
$(this).closest('tr');
```

Then from there you can find specific tds

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).addClass('whatever');
```

eq() takes an index position which will let you get a specific jQuery object from the result set to operate on.

Comment: what is eq(3) means?

Comment: 3 is the position, which is 0 based

Answer (score 0):

`this` is set to the element being clicked on your handler. Use that to backup and get the parent row, and then you can find the children

Comment: how to find child td by ordinal position?

Comment: I would not recommend using ordinal position but you can (nth-child selector if you insist) instead can you add semantic class names to those rows?  That makes for much nicer and robust code